# Do we need SSL certificate for XDBC server and HTTP server in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have two application servers and I want to have SSL certificates configured for both servers.

How can I configure SSL certificates for HTTP and XDBC application servers in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 4):

There is an entire section of the docs to walk you through this:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/SSL

Please note the sub-sections where there are topics likely of interest to you such as:

- Enabling SSL on an App server
- Importing SSL Certs

etc.

Comment: Thanks David, it doesn't have any dependency on different type of application like http or xdbc ...

Comment: SSL certificates can be configured for HTTP and XDBC servers. Same process. When configured, an HTTP server is accessed via https:// and an XDBC server via xccs:// and uses the configured certs.
"Enabling SSL for an App Server After creating a certificate template, you can enable SSL for an HTTP, ODBC, WebDAV, or XDBC server." 

  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/SSL#id_37057